# call services get error code 404 in asp boiler plate (apb) after added language to route config

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, aspnetboilerplate

I create new project base on ASP Boiler plate (abp).
I need to show language code in url. so my route config is :

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional}
                );

routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                    language = "fa",
                    title = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
            );
```

and i have front end code based on MVC Multy page that work correctly.
but in admin panel that based on single page angular js call all services get error 404!!!

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /api/services/app/role/GetRoles
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1038.0
>
> Resource not found! The resource requested could not found on the
>   server.

my service address call is : /api/services/app/role/GetRoles
and my route in admin panel is : http://localhost:6634/en/account#/roles

all java script loaded correctly.
all html views loaded correctly too.
but call all services fail and error 404.

please help me.
thanks.

Comment: May be the abp service address conflict with your route config name "DefaultApi"

Comment: What's in the error log?

Comment: Isn't it simply that `/api/services/app/role/GetRoles` doesn't map to anything? Shouldn't the url be /api/role/getRoles?